# Mysql update и прочее

Tags: c#, mysql

Здравствуйте! У меня есть таблица в которой есть 3 поля, и в которые я иногда записываю данные.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO items (Name, Href, Price) VALUES (@title, @href, @price1)";
```

Нужно создать 2 новых поля под названием NewPrice и Stats. Условие: когда я добавляю новые данные и в таблице есть такой href который я сейчас добавляю, записать только цену в поле NewPrice и добавить значение в  Stats(старое не трогать), если же нет, добавить 3 поля без новой цены и stats. Помогите с запросом. Примерно как должно все выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит добавить значение Stats(Старое не трогать) т.е. просуммировать ?

Comment: Используйте `insert ... on duplicate key update`. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+on+duplicate